# C++ expected a type specifier (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++-cli

I have tried many things. please help me.....

Full Source Code:

[Source Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/uY7XCrjT)

Troubled Code:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
DataTable table;

private: System::Void AcceptedApplications_Load(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {
MySqlCommand^ com = gcnew MySqlCommand("command", conn);
adapter = new MySqlAdapter(com);
}`
```

Comment: That's not C++ code. Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: should be tagged c++-cli

Comment: yes sorry @user4581301

Answer (score 1):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. Because of that, C++/CLI has all of the complexities of C++, all of the complexities of C#, and some complexities of its own. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
...
adapter = new MySqlAdapter(com);
```

A couple issues:

- It looks like you forgot the word "Data" when creating the object.
- According to [MySQL's reference site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm), that's a managed class. Therefore, it should have a `^` at the declaration and `gcnew` when instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

`public ref class` types generally need the ^ in C++/cli and gcnew.

```
MySqlDataAdapter^ adapter = gcnew MySqlDataAdapter();
DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable();
```